# Apply Code transformation after MSBuild

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I've got a Visual Studio 2015 solution that's composed of 2 parts

- Web Project (a main web project and referenced modules)
- WPF application (again, main one and modules).

Right now I've got a build server (Jenkins) that build server/client based on Build Profile (I've 12 build profile).

Since each build is the same except for the transformation. I was wondering if there's a way to build one time then to apply transformation later.

As far I've seen there's no specific MSBuild step to build passing a .config and it's specific .web.config, any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Use a generic cmd step (not sure how it's called in jenkins) and invoke msbuild from there?

Comment: but can msbuild just perform xtd transformation?

Comment: Ah, misunderstood the question. Yes, it can, VS uses msbuild under the hood for everything. As for making it do that: can't help you there, but you could figure out yourself. Key is knwoing what the msbuild Target is called: run a complete build with verbose logging. Check the log, figure out where it does the transform, note the name of the target involved, open the file where it's defined in a text editor, check what properties ('arguments') it needs. Then it's a matter of calling something like `msbuild /path/to/project /t:TargetWhichTransforms /p:ConfigFile=my.config`